# I am trying to do a trigger on username, no spaces

Tags: database, triggers

I am having trouble creating a trigger for my username field when adding new data, and any space kept needs to be combined/removed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Can you proved an example(s)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to [solve your own problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: username: sara parker
It should be saved in the database as: saraparker

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: oracle, db2  @a_horse_with_no_name